# how to add for loop control to each statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery

im new to jQuery.
I'm trying to use this script.

```
  __cnt__=0;
jQuery('.grid-cell .not-following .follow-text').each(function (i, ele) { 
    ele = jQuery(ele); 
    var ai = 0;
    setTimeout(function () {
      ele.click();
        return;
    }, __cnt__++*2000); 
  });
```

But this doesnt work and return this on chrome console:

> e.fn.init [prevObject: e.fn.init(1)]

Original script is this and works fine:

```
  __cnt__=0; jQuery('.Grid-cell .not-following .follow-text').each(function (i, ele) { 
ele = jQuery(ele); 
if (ele.css('display')!='block') {
console.log('already following:', i); return;} 
setTimeout(function () {ele.click();}, __cnt__++*2000); });
```

You can run above scripts on follower or following screens on twitter.
i really dont understand why mine dosnt work. please let me ask for your help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't use twitter. It would be helpful to include sample HTML for which your script would need to work. Twitter may not stick to the same HTML/classes in the future.

Comment: In the first example, you are using `.grid-cell` and in the second `.Grid-cell`